# Highlighting a certain part of a JTextArea

Tags: java, highlight

I'm trying to highlight a certain part of text in the text area that I've created. What my program does is that it shows a series of numbers delayed in a text area (for this code, it's 0-9). What I want is that I want to highlight numbers 2, 4, 6, 8. How will I use the highlighter for that? I don't want to search for string because I might highlight other digits. (For 28, it would highlight the 2). Any answer is appreciated. Thanks.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.List;


public class Test extends JFrame
{
    JPanel panel;
    JButton button;
    JTextArea tArea;
    SwingWorker<Void,String> worker;
    HandlerAction action = new HandlerAction();

    public Test() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        button = new JButton("Start");
        tArea = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane sPane = new JScrollPane(tArea);
        sPane.setBounds(0,0,100,100);
        button.setBounds(0,110,100,30);
        this.add(button);
        this.add(sPane);
        this.add(panel);
        button.addActionListener(action);
    }

    private class HandlerAction implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == button) {
                tArea.setText("");
                worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>(){
                    @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                            for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
                                publish(i + "\n");
                                sleep();
                            }
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
                            for (String line : chunks) {
                                tArea.append(line);
                                try {
                                     tArea.getHighlighter().addHighlight(0, 3, DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter);
                               } catch (BadLocationException err)                   {System.out.println(err)}
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    worker.execute();
                }
            };
        }
        public void sleep() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException err) {}
       }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test test = new test();
        test.setSize(200,200);
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        test.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I've added this

```
try {
    tArea.getHighlighter().addHighlight(0, 3, DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter);
} catch (BadLocationException err) {System.out.println(err)}
```

here

```
 @Override    
 protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
     for (String line : chunks) {  
            tArea.append(line);
      }
```

but it's highlighting all of the digits. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class names should start with an upper case character. Don't be lazy just because this is a SSCCE.

> I've added this to the process()

So update your code to show your new logic. We don't know where in the method you added the code.

> but it's highlighting all of the digits. Any Ideas?

How about adding an if statement to do conditional highlighting:

```
@Override
protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
    for (String line : chunks) {
        tArea.append(line);

        if  (line.length() == 2)
        {
            char first = line.charAt(0);

            if (first == '2'
            ||  first == '4'
            ||  first == '6'
            ||  first == '8')
            {
                try
                {
                    int offset = tArea.getDocument().getLength() - 2;
                    tArea.getHighlighter().addHighlight(offset, offset + 1, DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter);
                } catch (BadLocationException err) {System.out.println(err);}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't use an empty catch block. How will you know when you have an error?

Comment: Thanks. Is there another way of highlighting them? Maybe from the caret position? Because I'll make it a user- defined set of numbers. So I won't know what kind of inputs they'll make. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KevinNarra, Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved. I've given you proof of concept, I don't know your exact requirements so I can't give you an exact solution. Of course you can use the caret position if you think that will help. Also, my comment was about updating the original code so people can just copy/paste the code. We don't have time to put together multiple pieces of code into one class. We still can't tell for your description where you put the code. before/after the for loop, before/after the append statement.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections :) Anyways, when I try use it's caret position, I'm ending up highlighting different parts of the text. How would I do that?

Comment: @KevinNarra,  I would guess the caret would be at the end of the text so you need to subtract 2, like I do. But it is possible that the caret position hasn't been updated yet so it is point to the position in the document before the last line of text was added. Do some debugging to determines its value at the time you try to highlight the text.

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose for this line?
`if  (line.length() == 2) `

Comment: @KevinNarra, your requirement stated `I don't want to search for string because I might highlight other digits. (For 28, it would highlight the 2).`, so I added that as a condition to exclude highlighting the "2" in "28"